# Loading large amount of data into Postgres Hstore

Tags: postgresql, hstore

The hstore documentation only talks about using "insert" into hstore one row at a time.
Is there anyway to do a bulk upload of several 100k rows 
which could be megabytes or Gigs into a postgres hstore.

The copy commands seems to work only for uploading csv files  columns

Could someone post an example ? Preferably a solution that works with python/psycopg

Answer (score 6):

The above answers seems incomplete in that if you try to copy in multiple columns including a column with an hstore type and use a comma delimiter, COPY gets confused, like:

```
$ cat test
1,a=>1,b=>2,a
2,c=>3,d=>4,b
3,e=>5,f=>6,c

create table b(a int4, h hstore, c varchar(10));
CREATE TABLE;
copy b(a,h,c) from 'test' CSV;
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY b, line 1: "1,a=>1,b=>2,a"
```

Similarly:

```
copy b(a,h,c) from 'test' DELIMITER ',';
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY b, line 1: "1,a=>1,b=>2,a"
```

This can be fixed, though, by importing as a CSV and quoting the field to be imported into hstore:

```
$ cat test
1,"a=>1,b=>2",a
2,"c=>3,d=>4",b
3,"e=>5,f=>6",c

copy b(a,h,c) from 'test' CSV;
COPY 3
select h from b;
         h          
--------------------
 "a"=>"1", "b"=>"2"
 "c"=>"3", "d"=>"4"
 "e"=>"5", "f"=>"6"
(3 rows)
```

Quoting is only allowed in CSV format, so importing as a CSV is required, but you can explicitly set the field delimiter and quote character to non ',' and '"' values using the DELIMITER and QUOTE arguments for COPY.

Answer (score 3):

both insert and copy appear to work in natural ways for me

```
create table b(h hstore);
insert into b(h) VALUES ('a=>1,b=>2'::hstore), ('c=>2,d=>3'::hstore);
select * from b;
         h          
--------------------
 "a"=>"1", "b"=>"2"
 "c"=>"2", "d"=>"3"
(2 rows)

$ cat > /tmp/t.tsv
a=>1,b=>2
c=>2,d=>3
^d

copy b(h) from '/tmp/t.tsv';
select * from b;
         h          
--------------------
 "a"=>"1", "b"=>"2"
 "c"=>"2", "d"=>"3"
 "a"=>"1", "b"=>"2"
 "c"=>"2", "d"=>"3"
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this with the copy binary command.

I am not aware of a python lib that can do this, but I have a ruby one that can help you understand the column encodings.

https://github.com/pbrumm/pg_data_encoder